# django-numpy gives error with pip

Tags: python, django, numpy

I've been using django-numpy for some time now. But suddenly it gives an error, when I try to install it in a django project.
I've tried different approaches installing django-numpy - made a new venv - tried with another version og both django and django-numpy.
The error I get, when doing a `pip install -r requirements.txt` is:

```
Collecting django-numpy==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/b0/1f0be2e9c4df3b0736b09067dd041eb4475a6199b583428b241eb8576d7d/django-numpy-1.0.1.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-4qp99vp2/django-numpy/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip.download import PipSession
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.download'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip-install-4qp99vp2/django-numpy/
```

I've tried installing different packages via requirements, with no problems. It's only django-numpy that gives an error?

I do not know if I should make an issue on django-numpy's github?

Comment: do you have the latest version of pip? if not try to upgrade with `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: try also adding `--no-cache-dir` as argument to avoid cach

Comment: I'm using the latest version of pip. Adding `--no-cache-dir` gives the same error.

Comment: did you find out the solution?

Comment: No, so I stopped using it:-)